# Enticing users to join a paid subscription

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, signup-signon, subscription

my client reached out to me with a dilemma...as part of their mobile app, their is a monthly subscription service that shows you customized tutorials on how to apply make up etc....[image]

problem: how can we trigger the initiative to sign up through the UX and design...should there be a short video that shows a glimpse of what you can experience if you sign up? are there any other triggers that can work more effectively? are there similar examples out there and how do they approach such tasks? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could give them a free 30 day trial of the full paid experience and at the end of that prompt them to extend the full experience by paying.

Sometimes listing out the benefits or showing them in a video might not be enough for them to make a choice.

Comment: I agree with @Ameen. Freemium is the best way to increase your conversion rate. That way you can slow ease your users into becoming paid subscribers. As far as the OP's question is concerned: the trigger can be placed at the end of existing, free tutorials. You can also have thumbnails of paid content in the gallery section along with thumbnails of other free tutorials and differentiate the paid ones using a ribbon or some other visual cue.